# Error using the raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I have been using the raster calculator today to filter the relevant classifications for my data. My analysis spans over several rasters containing data from different years. I have been using it without issues for the first rasters, but for the last few, I kept getting an error.

The .tif file that I am using has the CRS "EPSG:28992 - Amersfoort / RD New", just like the prior years that ran without issues. The data includes land use of the Netherlands, the resolution increased in newer publications. There are a few additional classes in newer publications which are also filtered out.

[image: The function I'm using]

[image: The error that keeps occuring]

I have no clue what it means or why it suddenly appeared as the rasters aren't any different from the ones I used previously. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You could include some screenshots of the expression(s) you using and as well as some info about your raster data (CRS, etc), how did you create the classified rasters etc.

Comment: Hi Nikos, thanks for the feedback. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Given how long it was running for, and the "unknown" exception, you could be out of memory or other resources. If it's a large raster, consider splitting it into 2 or 4 and trying again?

Comment: Hi Tom Brennan. I was thinking the same yesterday. I managed to got one processed without error, but only when I didn't use any other other function on my PC. Made me think it was a RAM related issue indeed. I will try it again today without anyhting running alongside it. If that won't do the trick I'll get to splitting. Thanks for helping.